# WordPress Guest Author - How can I use custom fields to create guest author link?

Tags: wordpress, article, author

We are posting articles authored by guest authors. The guest authors will not be logging in to the site.

I've added a function so that my guest authors name will appear in place of the name of WordPress user who posted the article.. This function is outlined here:
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-rewrite-guest-author-name-with-custom-fields-in-wordpress/

Using this, I am able to change the name of the author to display the guest blogger's name.. However the author link still points to the author page of the WordPress user who posted the article.

So now I'd like to do something similar with the author link. What I would like to do is for the author link to come from a URL that I will enter in a custom field.

This is the code I'm using, but it's not working. The author link still takes you to the author page for the WordPress user who posted the article.

```
add_filter( 'the_author_posts_link', 'guest_author_link', 10, 3);
add_filter( 'get_author_posts_url', 'guest_author_link', 10, 3);
add_filter( 'the_author_link', 'guest_author_link', 10, 3);
add_filter( 'get_author_link', 'guest_author_link', 10, 3);

function guest_author_link($link, $author_id, $author_nicename) {
  global $post;
  $url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'guest-url', true );
    if( $url ) {
        $link = $url;
    }
    return $link;
}
```

Ideas?? Help...

Comment: This question should be on the wordpress version of this site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks.. I only asked here because I saw other WordPress function related questions.. Unfortunately none of them addressed my specific question..

Comment: thats cool just bear it in mind

Comment: Got it.. I have posted my question on the wordpress version of this site as well.. Hoping I get an answer soon.. I'm stumped here.. lol

Comment: Oh yes... Thanks Ollie for checking back.. I come to this site ALL THE time and find answers or hints that help me find answers.. this is the FIRST time I've had to ask a question.. Got a SWEEEEEEET solution!!!

Edited to add: I guess I should share the solution.. just in case someone finds this post.. :)

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110355/guest-author-how-can-i-use-custom-fields-to-create-guest-author-link#110355

Thanks again Ollie..

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Comment: An addendum to the above answer:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110501/guest-author-how-to-modify-my-custom-function-code-if-the-guest-author-url-wil